# Find places where a method has been overridden in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to find places where a method has been overridden in Android Studio? As I remember Eclipse has this feature by pressing Ctrl-T on the method to check. The find usage function doesn't seem to cover this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never tried doing this myself by I think that `ctrl+alt+b` might do the job. Found this info [here](http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-tricks-moving-around/)

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: That one is the shortcut for Right Click <abstract> method -> Go to... -> Implementation(s)

Answer (score 6):

In Android studio and Intellij IDEA, there is a blue icon with a down arrow just at the left of the method defination(only for overridden methods).

Click on that icon to get the list places where that method has been overridden.

Comment: Thank you, it's the same solution as Wndrr but he answered a little earlier. And also I'm biased towards the keyboard shortcut solution. Anyway I give you an upvote :)

Comment: Not a problem. Good thing is your question is answered. :)

Comment: This answer fits my case better than the accepted one. Clicking on the arrow leads me to the direct overriding code rather than showing the list of all files which contain the overridden method or method usages.

Answer (score 1):

I usually press `CTRL` and click on the method I wan't to see the usages of. For example when I want to see all `onCreate()` overrides from my app, I get this list.

[image]

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, it only find where the method has been called. But thank you.